# Is iti possible to find an element by a custom attribute?

Tags: intern

All elements in my web application are like that: `<div id="12ZD34" test-attr="elt1_stop2_3">` .

The id is automatically generated and change for each execution but not the test-attr attribute.

Is it possible to find testing elements by a custom attribute or an xpath from a custom attribute?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: You shouldn't use `test-attr` attribute. It's not valid. If You want some test attributes, use HTML5 `data-*` (for ex. `data-test`).

Answer (score 1):

Use jQuery:

$('div[test-attr="elt1_stop2_3"]')

Answer (score 0):

XPath would be:

```
//div[@test-attr='elt1_stop2_3']
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use LeadFoot's [findByXpath](http://theintern.github.io/leadfoot/Command.html#findByXpath):

```
this.remote.findByXpath("div[@test-attr='elt1_stop2_3']")
```